# A Big fancy "Q"

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures, ebgaramond

One time I remember seeing a Q ligature in `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}` (`fontspec`, EB Garamond, etc.) that involved a wonderful long swash. Now I don't know how to get it. Contrary to most other questions in this topic, how do I force this big *Q*?

Here's a (not too) minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xspace}
\defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}
%\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\cm#1{\relax}
\newcommand{\qsec}[1]{{\mbox{}\hfill\scshape #1}}
\newenvironment{qset}[1]{
        \mbox{}\\\qsec{#1}\par\begin{multicols}{2}
    }{
        \end{multicols}
    }
\newcommand{\q}[2]{{\em #1} #2\xspace}
%\def\q#1#2{{{\em #1} #2\xspace}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\fontspec[Ligatures={Required,Common,Contextual,Discretionary,TeX},Style=Alternate]{EB Garamond}
\noindent\mbox{Simon Kuang}\hfill\mbox{\today}
\centerline{\emph{Oedipus Rex} Study Guide Questions}
\begin{qset}
{First Episode --- Oedipus, Chorus, and Tiresias}
\noindent \q{Explain the following ironies in Oedipus's speech (218--220; 236--248; 249--251; 259--265).}{Que is.}
\end{qset}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that shows the problem? A simple example seems to give the Q you have in mind.

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe the problem is in all those packages.

Comment: @AlanMunn Also, this is LuaLaTeX. The swash only goes in XeLaTeX, I guess. Or maybe not?

Comment: The problem is the font size. If you change `11 pt` to `10 pt` you will get the long swash.  I'm not sure why. (And your example could be a lot more minimal.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select the font this way:

```
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Rare,ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=Contextual}]{EB Garamond}
```

This works even for your preferred font size, and with luatex as well as xetex.

If you examine the font in a program like FontForge, you will find that this delicious Q is called Q.long.  And if you search for Q.long in the feature file(s) (either using the feature files in the archives from [www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) or saving the feature file with FontForge), you’ll see that Georg Duffner, thanks to whom we have EB Garamond, has chosen to make Q.long accessible through the `calt` feature.

There’s no necessity here: designers of fonts can make alternate glyphs available in different ways.  So one needs to study any documentation the designers provide — it’s unfortunate that the `ebgaramond` package on CTAN omits Georg Duffner’s excellent documentation — or inspect the font with FontForge or similar programs, or experiment.

Comment: +1 Could you explain why this works and the original version doesn't?

Comment: @AlanMunn it’s the `calt` feature that isn’t enabled by default in LuaTeX (while it is in XeTeX and most other programs). You can enable it with `Contextuals=Alternate` or `RawFeature=+calt`. In the next update (some time in october) I’ll add an option to enable Q.long without contextual rules.