# How to force a long-tailed Q in EB Garamond

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ebgaramond

I'm using XeLaTeX and EB Garamond to produce a facsimile of a 17th-century French pamphlet.  EB Garamond, at least with its default settings, seems to select the long-tailed Q only when the Q is followed by at least three more characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Qu'il viue\\
Qui soubmettant\\
Quiconque vienne
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above example, showing that "Qui" has no long-tailed Q]

However, in the original pamphlet the long-tailed Q is used even for shorter words such as "Qui".  How can I get my document to use the long-tailed Q for the word "Qui"?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133380/7883

Comment: @Thérèse I tried and it doesn't work (XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX).

Comment: @egreg -- might adding an empty box help?

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, my impression is that the tail is used only if it ends short of the word. In the case of `Qaa` adding `\mbox{}` works, not with `Qui\mbox{}`

Comment: @egreg Right, because we’re fighting the contextual rules.  In `luatex` we can force the issue by using `fontchar{}` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120736/7883), but I don’t use `xetex` much and don’t know if there’s a way to use `XeTeXglyph` here, since EB Garamond does not play tricks with the Private Use Area (and it’s good that it doesn’t).

Comment: In `luatex` you can even write a feature file with `sub \Q by \Q.long;` so that you don’t need to remember to use the `\fontchar{}` macro every time Q appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With XeTeX you can force the glyph with `\XeTeXglyph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Rare]{EB Garamond}
\newcommand\Qlong{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "Q.long" \relax}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
\Qlong ui blablab

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Contextuals=Alternate` is the default for EB Garamond, according to the documentation.