# Force long tailed q in Small Caps EB Garamond

Tags: fontspec

Highly related:[How to force a long-tailed Q in EB Garamond](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210192/how-to-force-a-long-tailed-q-in-eb-garamond)

EB Garamond has a few different tails attached to 'Q', one of which is really long and pretty.  However, in small caps (which I want to use for post-nominal letters), I can't seem to get this longest tail, even though I can easily do so for the capital.  Is it possible to obtain the longest tail in small caps?

Problematic example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+ss06,+swsh,+smcp}]{EB Garamond}
\newcommand\Qlong{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "Q.long" \relax}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
\scshape \Qlong C \hspace{2ex} qc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You’ll get your desired output if you use EB Garamond from [Georg Duffner](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) instead of the EB Garamond modified (but not renamed, for reasons I can’t imagine) by [Octavio Pardo](https://github.com/octaviopardo/). TeX Live contains Pardo’s version.

Comment: @Thérèse Brilliant, thank you!