# A "swash" font feature differs between XeLaTeX and LuaLeTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, ebgaramond, swash

Compiling this example that uses [EB Garamond](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads) font

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{EB Garamond}[Ligatures=Historic,Scale=2]
Questo altere uniffatto fiato.
\end{document}
```

with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX gives two different results: the Q is shown with a long "swash" only in the PDF produced by XeLaTeX. Why?

[image]

Comment: In `luatex`, you need to specify `Contextuals=Alternate`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133385

Comment: Thank you, Thérèse. Looks like we have a duplicate here. My MWE is a bit cleaner, though.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title and body of your posting; technically, the font feature that's the subject of this posting isn't a ligature but a "swash".

Comment: Even cleaner if you get rid of `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}` and substitute `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`.  Or use the `\newfontface` or `newfontfamily` commands, which are more efficient than the `\fontspec` command.  (There’s a question about that somewhere on the site.)

Comment: XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX! This is the problem!